# Cognito Forms: Choose top 3 from a list

Tags: cognito-forms

I want to ask a question on my form that says "choose your top 3 choices from this list of 10 things." I'm sure there's a way to do this but how?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would recommend:

1. Open your form builder and add a Choice - Checkboxes field to your form.
2. Select Show Custom Error - When in the field settings. Click the
   Advanced Editor tab and insert the following expression:

   `=(FieldName.Count() != 3)`
3. Click Save.
4. Make sure to write a custom error message that appears when someone doesn't select the corrct number of options ("Please select 3 choices.")

Comment: I don't think that's the solution. The field label would be "Choose your top 3 choices from this list" then the Answers would be 2 parts: 1) Option # 2) 1st Choice, 2nd Choice, 3rd Choice. I'm guessing this would somehow be done as a Rating Scale field, but I can't figure out how to limit answers to 1 choice per option with a maximum of 3 choices, and no option can have the same choice. Make sense?

Comment: Ah, okay. If you want to have each option ranked, I believe it would be easier to just have three choice fields - one for each of the top 3 choices. Then, just set the custom error option for each choice field to ensure that the same choice cannot be selected twice. For example, to ensure that the third choice option doesn't match the other two, use the following expression: =(ThirdChoice = FirstChoice) or (ThirdChoice = SecondChoice)